# Highstock - series size and blank chart on start

Tags: highcharts

I know the "Dynamically updated data" example: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/dynamic-update

At the beginning my chart should be blank. I want to add points only using `series.addPoint()`.
So this code is the problem:

```
series : [{
name : 'Random data',
data : (function() {
    var data = [], time = (new Date()).getTime(), i;
    for( i = -999; i <= 0; i++) { // series size
        data.push([
        time + i * 1000,
        Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
        ]);
    }
    return data;
})()
```

After remove this part, the chart is not generated. I don't want to have contant limit of series size and any points just after the chart is created.

```
series : []
```

doesn't work, too.

Answer (score 0):

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mYwBB/) you can see an empty chart.

What happens in your case is that the code that runs into load event can't get the first serie bacause it doens't exist.

So, the following code is wrong.
`this.series[0];`

Change your code to the following and you'll have a serie without data:

```
series : [{
    name : 'Random data',
    data : []
}]
```

Comment: This example is completely useless. Did you try to add any point using `series.addPoint()`? Look http://jsfiddle.net/GGjNZ/

Comment: I adive to read more about [series.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint()) with shift argument. However, still min range can not be claculated, so you need to add null to that array, see: http://jsfiddle.net/GGjNZ/1/